# How short was Pharaoh?

Tags: parashas-shemos, egypt

What is the source that says the height of Pharaoh who enslaved the Jews in Egypt was very short? What was his exact height?

Comment: I remember being told that he was one amah in height. However, this is a *ruchnius* measurment just as Moshe Rabbeinu was said to be ten amos (when he killed Og). I do not think that this was an actual physical measurment.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Nach.1062.4

Comment: “We know” from where?

Comment: maybe check this out: https://dafyomi.co.il/mkatan/insites/mo-dt-018.htm

Comment: @sabbahillel Actually,you might find the archeological work done by Jim Long at Lightcatcher Studios of interest. He says that the Pharaoh of the exodus was in fact a dwarf. Long did a documentary years ago called the Riddle of the Exodus, I think. He shows statuary and carvings from several Egyptian Museums that seem to support that detail. Just like the Midrash detail that the Pharaoh before the exodus reigned for 94 years. There is only 1 Pharaoh in the hall of kings recorded to have reigned that long.

Comment: @sabbahillel Here's a link: https://www.amazon.com/Riddle-Exodus-Startling-Parallels-Archaeological/dp/0971938873

Answer (score 7):

The Gemara in [Moed Katan 18a](https://www.sefaria.org/Moed_Katan.18a.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says the Pharoh that was in the times of Moshe was 1 Amah.